# Почему проект не собирается на флешке

Tags: linux, c, debian, gcc

Забилась внутренняя память линукса и теперь пытаюсь собрать проект на флешке.
Как собрать проект на флешке ???

- примонтировал флешку `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/usb`
- вызвал команду `gcc main.c -o trem` находясь на флешке и в директории проекта

результат на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему-то не собралось хотя места полно, что я делаю не так ??

Comment: там же красным подсвечено, что в `/tmp` место законичилось. так что нужно еще `/tmp` перемонтировать на флешку в какой-нить каталог. ну и если от `sudo` работать, на диске еще 10% места будет, это зарезервировано для починки системы, когда место реально закончилось

Comment: @TotalPusher а как подчистить просто аж совсем трех гигов нахватает. Я   своё все удалил, может нужно всякие библиотеки удалить ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ошибке написано, что не так: "Ошибка записи в /tmp/ccKBkRaa.s: Нет места на устройстве". Нужно изменить каталог временных файлов. Попробуйте так:

```
TMPDIR=/mnt/usb gcc main.c -o trem
```